# Find all integers $x$ that are at most $100000$ so that $S(11x) = x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, decimal-expansion

> For a positive integer $x,$ let $S(x)$ denote the sum of the squares of the digits of $x$.

1. Find all integers $x$ that are at most $100000$ so that $S(11x) = x$.
2. Prove or disprove whether there are infinitely many $x$ so that $S(11x) = x$.

I know that the two digit integers $x=50,73$ both work. Among the one digit numbers $x$, $S(11x) > x$. I think it's useful to observe that once $S(11x)$ exceeds $x$, for any $y$ larger than $x$ with only the units digit differing from $x, S(11y) > y,$ though I'm not sure how to prove this. Similarly, for any $y$ smaller than $x$ with only the units digit differing from $x, S(11y) < y$ if $S(11x) < x$. For the proof, I think one could start by writing $x = 100 a + 10b + c, y = 100a + 10b + d,$ where $a$ is a nonnegative integer and $b,c,d$ are digits. From this, one has $11x = 1100 a + 110 b + 11c, 11y = 1100a + 110b + 11d.$

Comment: Can't be infinite.  If $x$ has $k$ digits then $11k$ will have at the very most $k+2$ digits.  The sum of the squares of the $k+2$ is at the very most $9^2(k+2)$ And $11k$ is at the very least $10^{k+1}$.  $\log 9^2(k+2) =2\log 9+\log(k+2)< 2 + \log(k+2)$ and $\log 10^{k+1}$ so if we have $k+1 >\log (k+2) + 2$ we'll have $S(11x)=x$ being impossible. (Quick and dirty I don't think we can have more than 4 digits but I haven't don't the work.)

Comment: Hmm... *somethings* wrong with my math there but my reasoning is sound.  The size of $S(x)$ increases linear with the number of digits and $x$ increases exponentially with the digits.  There is always an upper limit to $S(M\cdot x) \ge x$.

Comment: @fleablood I don't think even $4$ digits is possible. Assume $k=3$. Then $\max(S(11k))=324$. (We get a *lower* number with a $5$-digit $11k$; if $k=3$ and $11x$ has $5$ digits, then $S(11x) \le 227$. It's $227$ for $x=999, 11x=10989$.) At $4$ digits, the maximum is $S(11x)=405$, and so forth. We need $11x$ to have $13$ digits to get $S(11x) \ge 1000$. So our maximum solution must be $x \le 324$.

Comment: Also, I see no way to get a useful closed-form expression to find $x$. I think only a computer search will do it. Also note that as $S(11x)$ is the sun of four squares, any number works; we can't skip any problem numbers like we could have with two digits.

Comment: One last follow-up: SageMath confirms that your two solutions are *all* of the solutions, and that (for instance), $S(11x) < 200$ for $x <509$.  [Code here, a couple seconds to run up to $x=1000$](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy9SyFPIzFOINtTTMzQwMIi14uXi5VIAgmwFWwVDQwUthTyYSDBQxADCTAPqywTpy9ZLyUzPLCnW0LSCyMAUBitoK2TGGUEEC4oy80o08nQUsnUUgjUBtXoZSA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is reasonable but fails for $n=90$, as $S(11\cdot90) = 162>90$ but $S(11\cdot91) = 2<91$.

Let's fix $n \ge 1$ and find a bound on $S(11x)$ where $x$ has exactly $n$
digits:
$$ \overbrace{110...0}^{n+1} \le 11x \lt \overbrace{1100...0}^{n+2}, $$
which implies $S(11x) \le S(\overbrace{99...99}^{n+1}) = 9^2(n+1)=81n+81$. For
$n \ge 4,$ it can be shown by induction on $n$ that $81n+81 < 10^{n-1} \le x$
for any $x$ with $n$ digits. Thus there are no solutions with more than 3
digits, and the second question has a negative answer.

For $n=1$ there are no solutions by inspection.

For $n=2,3$ there are no more solutions besides $x=50,\ 73$. As a first bound,
note that if $x = S(11x),$ then by the previous argument,
$$x = S(11x) < 81\cdot4 = 324.$$
For $182 \le x \le 324,\ \ 3000 \le 11x \le 3564 \implies x = S(11x) \le S(3599) = 196.$ So any answer is smaller than 196.

A computer search shows the only 2 solutions are the ones you gave; however, for $x$ below $179$ it gets harder as $S(11 \cdot 179)>179$. I don't know if there is a fast manual way to find the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the point of my question was to find a manual way to solve it.